# Custom CharacterEscapeHandler not firing in spring boot application (Jaxb2Marshaller)

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, soap, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am trying to configure the marshaller so that it does not convert **'<' to '& lt;'** et.
I have implemented a custom CharacterEscapeHandler but it does not seem to fire when i make a request.
I have found some similar threads but unfortunately there is no valid solution. I even read that this is a spring bug, i am hopping it is not.
My code is

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();

    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

    props.put("com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler",
            new CharacterEscapeHandler() {
                @Override
                public void escape(char[] ac, int i, int j, boolean flag,
                        Writer writer) throws IOException {
                    System.out.println("I AM HERE");
                    writer.write(ac, i, j);
                }
            });
    marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(props);

    marshaller.setContextPaths(path);
    return marshaller;
}


@Bean
public SOAPClientConnector soapConnector(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    SOAPClientConnector client = new SOAPClientConnector();
    client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    return client;
}
```

And i use it like this.

```
getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(url, request);
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm experiencing the same issue.